# Can I renew my blue card (from Germany) even if my passport expired?

Tags: germany, passport, blue-card

I'm from a non-EU country and I have a blue card from Germany and I'm working there. Both my passport and the blue card are going to expire at the same time in a year from now.

When my passport expires, I won't be able to renew for at least 9 months after the expiry time. That's because my country's embassy will not renew my passport unless I provided them with a specific document which I won't be able to obtain except after 9 months of the expiry of my passport.

Is there any way to renew my blue card even if my passport is already expired ? or maybe is there any way to temporarily extend my blue card for these 9 months till I actually get a new passport ?

Or maybe, is there any alternative identification document that I can apply for from the German authorities that I can use when renewing my blue card ?

Also, if the same situation happened but I've a permanent residency instead of a blue card, are there any difference ?

I'm basically trying to find a legal way to allow me to stay in Germany and work there during these 9 months where both my passport and blue card has already expired. I don't care about my ability to travel abroad during this time, only about my ability to stay in Germany and work there.

Comment: (+1) I don't know for a fact (hence no answer) but there are countries where renewing a residence permit is possible without passport. However, Germany tends to be rather finicky with this kind of things and holding a valid, officially sanctioned, form of ID is in fact mandatory there so I would not be surprised if they expect you to renew your passport no matter what and would not be very friendly to the notion that you have to wait 9 months for that. What's this mysterious document? Is there absolutely no way to renew your passport earlier?

Comment: Gala: Unfortunately there's no way to renew the passport without the document.

Comment: OK, but what is it and why can't you get it? I would try to look into that (perhaps ask a question about it?)

Comment: Your blue card visa (the _Aufenthaltstitel_ card) is only valid together with the _Beiblatt_ piece of paper that lists the job types **and** your passport. It's linked to the passport because the passport number is on the physical card. If the passport expires, the visa is invalid. It's not expired though. You can still get a new passport and then get a new physical card. Your right to the visa remains intact. You just don't have a valid visa, which is kind of bad.

Comment: I cannot say for sure that it can be done because I have a similar story with a fried now and it was solved by the Auslanderbehörde that they gave him an exemption of the passport request but he was walking around with a paper saying that his application is on hold until he gets a new passport. It would be helpful as well if you can share your experience since you had this question for more than 2 years now, so I hope you found a way around it.

Comment: May I ask you what have you done cuz I have a similar situation here?

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can renew your passport before it expires if you have the right documents. Do that in your embassy in Germany. Tell your local *Auslaenderbehoerde* that you are going to do that. Your old passport will still be valid until it's date is past, unless they invalidate it (i.e. they make holes in it). In any case, tell your embassy you want to keep it. Then go to Auslaenderbehoerde as soon as you know your new passport number and tell them it changed. They will issue you a temporary paper for your 19a blue card visa, and start producing a new physical *Aufenthaltstitel* card for you. You will have to pay for that and it will take a month.

While you don't have that card, you cannot leave Germany.

Source: I helped someone do this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that once your blue card expires you've probably been in Germany long enough to get a _Niederlassungserlaubnis_ if your German skills are high enough. When you have that, you never need to talk to Auslaenderbehoerde again, and the 19a salary range goes away, while the spouse benefits should stay. I don't have a source for the last. I've asked people in Berlin's _Auslaenderbehoerde_ and they said it would stay, but couldn't name sources. Anyway, having that one is the better deal. In Berlin, they take the card and stick a visa in your passport for _Niederlassungserlaubnis_.

Comment: @sinbabque While this is helpful, and addresses the issue of remaining legally in Germany, the OP has stated that he cannot renew his passport without a specific document which he _won't be able to obtain except after 9 months of the expiry_ of his passport. The OP hasn't responded to the Gala request for details on that 'document' in order to prompt suggested remedy, and OP hasn't returned to TSE in nearly a month.

Comment: @Dorothy oh. I misread that part. You're right. I'll edit but leave the answer standing as it does contain useful info.

Answer (score 0):

My wife's German permanent residency permit has its validity limited to her passport's expiration so don't count on having a permanent residency without a valid passport.
It sounds like the blue card doesn't have the same limitation (since yours will expire later than the passport); but I recommend that you try to sort out your password before the renewal date.

Answer (score 0):

> That's because my country's embassy will not renew my passport unless I provided them with a specific document which I won't be able to obtain except after 9 months of the expiry of my passport.

Did they confirm this in writing?

If not, get one (preferably also with a German text) stating these reasons clearly.

If your Embassy refuses to give a reason in writing., report this situation to the Ausländerbehörde.

Based on this a [**Foreigners Passport**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiseausweis_f%C3%BCr_Ausl%C3%A4nder) *could* be issued based on § 5 AufenthV for the time needed.

Based on this Passport, a residence permit can then be issued.

---

> **Aufenthaltsverordnung (AufenthV)**
>   **§ 5 Allgemeine Voraussetzungen der Ausstellung des Reiseausweises für Ausländer**
>   (1) Einem Ausländer, der nachweislich keinen Pass oder Passersatz besitzt und **ihn nicht auf zumutbare Weise erlangen kann**, kann nach Maßgabe der nachfolgenden Bestimmungen ein Reiseausweis für Ausländer ausgestellt werden.
>   (2) Als zumutbar im Sinne des Absatzes 1 gilt es insbesondere,
>
> > 1. derart rechtzeitig vor Ablauf der Gültigkeit eines Passes oder Passersatzes bei den zuständigen Behörden im In- und Ausland die erforderlichen Anträge für die Neuerteilung oder Verlängerung zu stellen, dass mit der Neuerteilung oder **Verlängerung innerhalb der Gültigkeitsdauer des bisherigen Passes oder Passersatzes gerechnet werden kann**,
> >        ...
>
> **Residence Ordinance (AufenthV)**
>   **§ 5 General requirements for issuing a travel document for foreigners**
>   (1) A foreigner who demonstrably does not have a passport or passport substitute and **cannot obtain it in a reasonable manner** can be issued a travel document for foreigners in accordance with the following provisions.
>   (2) In particular, within the meaning of paragraph 1
>
> > 1. it is deemed to submit the necessary applications for a new or renewal to the competent authorities in Germany and abroad in good time before the expiry of a passport or passport replacement, that the renewal or **renewal can be expected within the validity period of the previous passport or passport replacement**,
> >        ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Reiseausweis für Ausländer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiseausweis_f%C3%BCr_Ausl%C3%A4nder)
- [§ 5 Allgemeine Voraussetzungen der Ausstellung des Reiseausweises für Ausländer - Aufenthaltsverordnung (AufenthV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__5.html)