# Can I apply for "Deutsche Passersatzpapiere für Ausländer" if it is too complicated to renew my passport at my Embassy?

Tags: germany, residency

Is it possible to apply for a German passport substitution or a German travel document for foreigners as my embassy is making it more and more complicated to renew my passport and I will have to wait for at least 9 months and I urgently need to renew my residency?

Comment: The 'complication' and time it takes to get your passport is not relevant. If you hold one (even expired) or can reasonably (in other words it won't be denied because you are not a citizen), then the Deutsche Passersatzpapiere für Ausländer is not meant for you. That's more situations such as asylum seekers or people whose citizen isn't known or decided yet, or even stateless people.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot. According to [the §5 of the *Aufenthaltsverordnung*](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthV/5.html)  a *Reiseausweis für Ausländer* can only be issued for a person who does not possess a passport of their home country or cannot obtain it in a reasonable way. You do possess a passport of your home country and you can renew it in time if you apply early enough (§5 s.2).

Comment: No, even if I apply early enough, it will take me at least 9 months after the expiry date of my current one cuz many paperwork have to be fulfilled till my age of 30.

Comment: Honestly, I don't quite understand your comment. If you know that the renewal takes more than 9 months you have to apply taking that timespan into account.

Comment: @ouba2 What do you mean by "many paperwork have to be fulfilled till my age of 30"?  "till" is definitely wrong.  Do you mean "many pieces of paperwork cannot be provided before I am 30"? Or do you mean "many pieces of paperwork are required because I am 30"?

Comment: @ouba2  The German authorities will assume you *should* have known how long it would take to renew your passport.  If it came as a nasty shock to you, then I am afraid that is your problem.

Comment: @Ex Patriot: I need a piece of paper to be able to renew my passport and I won`t get this paper until I reach 30 years old. That will take 5 months after the expiry of my current passport and add 4 months at least for my embassy to process my application and issue me a new passport.

Comment: @Martin Bonner: Exactly, I cannot obtain a necessary piece of paper needed for the passport application until I reach 30, only then I can apply for a new one. and there are 5 months between my current passport expiry date and me reaching 30

Comment: I kinda have the same situation as this post: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9081/can-i-renew-my-blue-card-from-germany-even-if-my-passport-expired

Comment: You have to ask at the responsible German authority then.

Comment: This answer makes an assumption that "cannot obtain it in a reasonable way" isn't applicable in this case, which could be incorrect.  Do you have any examples of impediments to obtaining a passport that have been held to be reasonable or unreasonable?

Comment: @phoog §5 Absatz 2 Nr 1 describes exactly such a situation (i.e. which was before clarification about 30-years-problem) as "zumutbar".

Comment: @ExPatriot but now it is clear that the item you cite does not apply here.  I would question whether it's truly required to apply for the renewal 9 months after the expiration, but if we assume that it is, then it seems that the inability to obtain the passport is reasonable.  If the reason for having to apply 9 months late is discretionary, then presumably the justification for making that choice would have to be reasonable (I'm thinking vaguely of something having to do with compulsory military service, for example).  More information is needed to determine whether §5 applies here.

Comment: @phoog: Yeah I asked at my embassy for renewing the passport before its expiry date and they told me that I have either to wait here till I reach 30 and then get this piece of paper from the military office at the embassy or I can go to my home country and also I will still have to wait till 30 and then do the same (of course with even more bureaucracy) and obtain this paper and then apply for the passport in my home country. The time-span wont change whether here or there. But of course I will result of me losing my job here cuz I have only 25 days of holidays.